# Nested multi value specifiers in iPhone app's Settings bundle

Tags: iphone, settings, nested, bundle, multivalue

I am trying to add nested multi value specifiers to my app's Settings bundle (something like what is done in the "Region Format" section of the International settings in the Settings app).

I have tried to use a PSMultiValueSpecifier for the first set of values (first screen, like the list of languages in "Region Format") and then setting the value of some of the items (in the Values array) to PSMultiValueSpecifier again, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use PSChildPaneSpecifier: http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=274

Comment: The problem if I use PSChildPaneSpecifier is that it would allow to choose more than one value in the first screen. If you see the Region Format settings, the first screen (where you choose the language) acts like a PSMultiValueSpecifier, where you can only select one of the values.

Also, when selecting the region in the second screen, it automatically goes back to the first one (languages), without having to tap on the back button, so the behaviour is a bit different than the normal PSMultiValueSpecifier.